# Why am I getting Error, Argument is of Length 0 in Loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the number of time each row in my dataframe have both "Passed" in the result column and "Yes" in position. However, I'm getting an error in a loop I'm running.

```
Error in if (current$position == "Yes" & current$result == "Passed") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I heard that this can happen when you compare to `null` or `NA` values but the values in the table are never `null` or `NA`.

This is the code I have for my loop.

```
count_votes <- 0
recent <- slice(flatten_votes, 1:20)

for (i in 1:length(recent)) {
  current <- slice(recent, i)
  if (current$position == "Yes" & current$result == "Passed") {
    count_votes = count_votes + 1
  }
}
```

[This is what the first few rows of the dataframe look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SdZB.png)

Comment: If you search a little more through stackoverflow, you will find this exact error numerous times. If you manually run your loop (I'd check both `i <- 1` and `i <- length(recent)` for starters), and then check the "if" condition manually, you will find that it does not always return exactly one `logical` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a loop to do that. Why don't you just write the following:

```
my.df = flatten_votes #or recent
passed_and_yes <- my.df[my.df$position == "Yes" & my.df$result == "Passed",]
count_votes <- nrow(passed_and_yes)
```

Hope that helps.